Understanding AFL behaviour for fork and execv; Why `/proc/<pid>/maps` does not show the loaded binary
TL;DR Why process map in /proc/<pid>/maps does not show where the executed binary is loaded?
I am trying to do some post-mortem analysis of the fuzzed program once it finishes.
Basically what I am seeing is that /proc/<pid>/maps shows what looks to be the memory map of the parent instead of the child. I was unable to replicate the behavior on a smaller scale but I'll provide a patch to github.com/google/AFL. (Add an empty raw after the else last row if patch fails)
diff --git a/afl-fuzz.c b/afl-fuzz.c
index 46a216c..e31125f 100644
--- a/afl-fuzz.c
+++ b/afl-fuzz.c
@@ -2283,6 +2283,14 @@ EXP_ST void init_forkserver(char** argv) {

 }

+static void read_map(int pid, char *map) {
+    FILE *proc;
+    char path[50];
+    sprintf(path, "/proc/%d/maps", pid);
+    proc = fopen(path, "r");
+    fread(map, 4096, 1, proc);
+    fclose(proc);
+}

 /* Execute target application, monitoring for timeouts. Return status
    information. The called program will update trace_bits[]. */
@@ -2423,7 +2431,14 @@ static u8 run_target(char** argv, u32 timeout) {

   if (dumb_mode == 1 || no_forkserver) {

-    if (waitpid(child_pid, &status, 0) <= 0) PFATAL("waitpid() failed");
+    int res;
+    char map[4096];
+    while (!(res = waitpid(child_pid, &status, WNOHANG))) {
+        if (res < 0)
+            PFATAL("waitpid() failed");
+        read_map(child_pid, map);
+    }
+    printf("%s\n", map);

   } else {


After applying the patch you can run the following to check things out
mkdir input output
echo "hello" > input/test1
./afl-fuzz -i input -o output -n -- /bin/ls

What you'll probably is the map for afl-fuzz?
The patch is waiting for the execv to finish while reading the /proc/<pid>/maps, once it's finished prints the last map that was read.
I'm curious what I am missing in me reading the map or what triggers this. (Also I don't think this is regarding AFL itself is just where I've seen this, it would be nice to see a smaller program that replicates the behavior since I was unable to replicate it)

I don't fully understand the question, but you might find find Fuzzing random programs without execve() helpful. Also check out AFL++, the successor of AFL.

The blog linked does not apply since it only applies for the forkserver, where seemingly the grandkids execute the binaries. My question can probably be resumed to  "why doesn't the memory map of the child show where the executed binary was loaded"
